# Replaced clutch on '84 Bronco 2, now clutch does not disengage

Tags: ford, clutch, bronco, throw-out-bearing

I replaced the clutch on an '84 Ford Bronco 2 (2.9L). After removing the transmission I found out that the throw-out bearing and slave cylinder were completely destroyed. I replaced both parts and thoroughly bled the hydraulic clutch lines.

After I was done with the install the clutch pedal has a little pressure but will not disengage the clutch to allow the transmission to go into another gear.

After researching online I think I may have put the self-centering throw-out bearing in the wrong direction. Please help. How do I know which direction to place the bearing?

Comment: Are you sure you got the proper slave cylinder? If it has too short a stroke it will not engage the clutch.

Comment: You're dead sure you bled the slave cylinder completely? What you describe is symptomatic of air in the slave cylinder.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. I believe it would be pretty hard to get the throw out bearing in
   backwards. **Flat side towards the clutch**, right? it *may* be the
   case, but I find it highly unlikely. (See the picture below) What you see
   is the side which goes towards the transmission. **NOTE:** This type of throwout bearing is supposed to be self aligning ... that is the reason for the pointy part. In practice it doesn't work that well, but at any rate, the pointy part should be **away** from the clutch fork.
2. How tight did you tighten bolts for the pressure plate to the
   flywheel? The spec calls for 15-24 ft lbs. This is not a lot of
   torque (may more easily be done using an inch-pound torque wrench at
   180-288 in lbs). If you used a ratchet and just had at it, the
   assembly is probably too tight and may be causing your issues.
3. **EDIT:** A third problem may be that the slave cylinder is pushing away from the clutch pedal, flexing the firewall. If it is, you'll need to reinforce the firewall. You can have someone pump on the pedal to see if there is any movement while you watch it.

[image: Throw out bearing for Bronco II]

Comment: I torqued the pressure plate to 15 ft lbs with a torque wrench. Yes I have the throw-out bearing installed the right direction, as you described with the picture. The part on the throw-out bearing that comes to a point, now does it matter what direction that's pointed?

Comment: The smaller end of the throwout bearing goes toward the transmission, the larger end goes toward the clutch.

Comment: @Paulster... I don't think I've ever seen a pressure plate that didn't seat fully against the flywheel. Too much torque could break off the bolts, though. Too **little** torque might permit the pressure plate to "float", which might permit its fingers from extending far enough...

Comment: @TDHofstetter ... I'm actually talking about too much clamping force caused by the bolts if done too tight. If like this, the pressure plate will not release the friction disk correctly. If it isn't tight enough, the friction disk will slip because it does not have enough grip on the flywheel and clutch plate.

Comment: @Paulster2, I understand warping the pressure plate by not torquing it down in the correct sequence, but I can't imagine how overtightening the bolts that hold the PP's outer shell could distort anything once the bolts have been seated. Greater bolt torque would just stretch the bolts more, bring them nearer to failure (breaking off). Ah, no matter - by now that clutch has probably long since been fixed. Poor ol' addlepated "Community" hauled it back to the top because it was never "accepted".

Comment: @TDHofstetter ... I think you are misunderstanding. It doesn't *warp* the clutch plate so much as it pulls it tighter to the flywheel. If you over tighten the bolts, it will not let the friction disk go, causing it to have release problems. Think about it, you could tighten 3/8" bolts much tighter than 15-24 ft lbs without bolt damage. There is a reason they only want you to tighten them this little.

Comment: But the outer shell around the pressure plate **seats** against the flywheel. Tightening the bolts doesn't seat it any more, and the lands around the bolt holes are flat to match the flywheel surface, so overtightening the bolts can't pull the shell any tighter. Here's a random photo grabbed from Google for illustration: https://www.speedwaymotors.com/rs/cmr/TechPics/flathead-gm-clutch-pressure-plate.jpg

Comment: @TDHofstetter ... It doesn't matter what logic is telling you, this is the way it happens. We could talk about it for days, but maybe it would be better to take it to the chat.